VFP register args linker errors while compiling a rust binary for ARMv7/Cortex-A9
I just recently started messing around with cross compilation and playing around with ARM in general, so I am pretty sure there is something I am missing here.
I am trying to see if I can compile the basic minimal.rs Smithay example for ARM to see if this is even possible. I have no idea where I want to wake this afterwards however.
I've managed to compile a kernel and all the libs to test against with buildroot, I have also set up all ARMhf libs in the host system (using Ubuntu for this), hopefully correctly...
The error I am getting basically boils down to about 700 lines of stuff like:
warning: `smithay` (lib) generated 1 warning (1 duplicate)
  Compiling winmngr v0.1.0 (/home/dave/projects/embedded/winmngr)
warning: unstable feature specified for `-Ctarget-feature`: `d32`
  |
  = note: this feature is not stably supported; its behavior can change in the future

warning: unstable feature specified for `-Ctarget-feature`: `vfp2`
  |
  = note: this feature is not stably supported; its behavior can change in the future

warning: unstable feature specified for `-Ctarget-feature`: `vfp3`
  |
  = note: this feature is not stably supported; its behavior can change in the future

error: linking with `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc` failed: exit status: 1
  |
  = note: LC_ALL="C" PATH="...
= note: /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/13/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: error: /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/13/crtbeginS.o uses VFP register arguments, /home/dave/projects/embedded/target/armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/release/deps/winmngr-a08288288ddb65da does not
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/13/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: failed to merge target specific data of file /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/13/crtbeginS.o
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/13/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: error: /home/dave/projects/embedded/target/armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/release/deps/winmngr-a08288288ddb65da.winmngr.310e3d8b3a5cfd8a-cgu.00.rcgu.o uses VFP register arguments, /home/dave/projects/embedded/target/armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/release/deps/winmngr-a08288288ddb65da does not
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/13/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: failed to merge target specific data of file /home/dave/projects/embedded/target/armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/release/deps/winmngr-a08288288ddb65da.winmngr.310e3d8b3a5cfd8a-cgu.00.rcgu.o
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/13/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: error: /home/dave/projects/embedded/target/armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/release/deps/winmngr-a08288288ddb65da.winmngr.310e3d8b3a5cfd8a-cgu.01.rcgu.o uses VFP register arguments, /home/dave/projects/embedded/target/armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/release/deps/winmngr-a08288288ddb65da does not
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/13/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: failed to merge target specific data of file /home/dave/projects/embedded/target/armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/release/deps/winmngr-a08288288ddb65da.winmngr.310e3d8b3a5cfd8a-cgu.01.rcgu.o
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/13/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: error: /home/dave/projects/embedded/target/armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/release/deps/winmngr-a08288288ddb65da.winmngr.310e3d8b3a5cfd8a-cgu.02.rcgu.o uses VFP register arguments, /home/dave/projects/embedded/target/armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/release/deps/winmngr-a08288288ddb65da does not
...

Am I correctly understanding that all the other files (dependencies, libs), which are compiled for hardfloat with VFP support are incompatible with my own winmngr, which for some reason isn't built with VFP support?
I am also using a custom target json file:
{
    "arch": "arm",
    "data-layout": "e-m:e-p:32:32-Fi8-i64:64-v128:64:128-a:0:32-n32-S64",
    "dynamic-linking": true,
    "env": "gnu",
    "executables": true,
    "features": "+strict-align,+v6,+vfp3",
    "has-elf-tls": true,
    "has-rpath": true,
    "is-builtin": false,
    "linker-flavor": "gcc",
    "linker-is-gnu": true,
    "linker": "arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc",
    "llvm-target": "armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf",
    "max-atomic-width": 64,
    "os": "linux",
    "position-independent-executables": true,
    "pre-link-args": {
        "gcc": [
            "-Wl,--as-needed",
            "-Wl,-z,noexecstack",
            "-mfloat-abi=softfp"
        ]
    },
    "relro-level": "full",
    "target-c-int-width": "32",
    "target-endian": "little",
    "target-family": "unix",
    "target-mcount": "_mcount",
    "target-pointer-width": "32",
    "vendor": "unknown"
}

And I run nightly cargo build this way with nightly toolchain for the std-build:
export PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ 
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/pkgconfig 
export RUSTFLAGS="-C linker=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -C target-feature=+vfp3,-vfp2 -L /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/13" 
cargo +nightly build --release --target armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf.json -Z build-std=std,alloc # &> build-output.txt

I feel like over the past week I got through a ton of errors and learned a lot, but this seems to be beyond me right now. What am I missing? Does anyone have any pointers?
--I believe this should be enough context, but in case you would like to look into the rest of the project, here is a link to the gist with more details

Why do you have -mfloat-abi=softfp if you're compiling for gnueabihf?

Oop forgot to update the code on here. I already removed it from my project but it wasn't enough
